# MVC site when on web server, only can access home page

Tags: .net, model-view-controller, deployment, webserver

I have a very small MVC site (only a few controllers and views) that works fine when running locally. However when I publiush the site to a web server there are issues. The home page log in screen is displayed, but if I attempt to log in past that page it just comes up with 404 errors and the pages not being able to be found.

I thought this was initially because on the web server I have it in a subfolder called "file upload" so the web browser was trying to go fileupload/controller/action instead of controller/action. However, after messing about with manually putting in the location I still just get 404 errors.

This isn't an issue with the version of MVC like I have seen mentioned elsewhere.

I'm not really sure what other information to give as I have no idea what is causing this. Any ideas are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Have you enabled windows authentication ?
If yes, is the hosted environment can access your Active directory?
[Authorize] attribute for authenticated access and permissions on folders
Points to begin investigation